# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 After XCode 12 update

Tags: xcode, react-native, openssl, cocoapods, xcode12

I recently updated XCode version to XCode 12 and started to encounter this error

```
ld: in /project_path/ios/Pods/OpenSSL-Universal/ios/lib/libcrypto.a(cryptlib.o),

building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS,

file '/project_path/ios/Pods/OpenSSL-Universal/ios/lib/libcrypto.a' for architecture arm64
```

`clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

I am unable to run or archive the project

I have tried the following to fix this error with no success

deleted pods folder and reinstalled
updated pods
Excluded arm64 architecture for debug

I am not sure what is causing the error.

Please help

Comment: Does this happen only in Xcode 12? Have you re-validate by building again with Xcode 11? At least the message it's clear. The library can only build with Simulator, not physical device.

Comment: @TommyLeong I have not revalidated it by building with XCode 11 because the issue was encountered only after XCode update

Comment: You should probably try it with Xcode 11, so you can really confirm the issue with Xcode12.

Comment: Okay, I wlll Give it a try Thank you

Comment: Happening to me as well. Apple really pooped the bed with this iOS 14 release. Xcode 12 is still in beta...

Comment: @TommyLeong It is building successfully in XCode 11.7

Comment: The only solution I found so far to run on Simulator (only): https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/657913
Hopefully we'll get a proper solution soon

Comment: I have the same issue. Any solution ?

Comment: Created this issue: https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/OpenSSL/issues/103